# If $A$ is a subset of the real line $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q \subseteq A$ which of the following must be true?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $A$ is a subset of the real line $\mathbb R$ and $A$ contains each rational number, which of the following must be true?
>
> (a) If $A$ is open, then $A = \mathbb R$.
>
> (b) If $A$ is closed, then $A = \mathbb R$.
>
> (c) If $A$ is uncountable, then $A = \mathbb R$.
>
> (d) If $A$ is uncountable, then $A$ is open.
>
> (e) If $A$ is countable, then $A$ is closed.

**My Approach:**

(a) False. $A$ could be say $\mathbb R\setminus \{\sqrt{2}\}$ which is open as it is basically the union of two open sets $(-\infty, \sqrt 2) \cup (\sqrt 2, \infty)$.

(b) True. $\bar {\mathbb Q}$ is the smallest closed set containing $\mathbb Q$. And we know $\bar {\mathbb Q} = \mathbb R$. So if $A$ is closed, then $A = \bar A = \mathbb R$. It couldn't possibly be larger than $\mathbb R$.

(c) False. $\mathbb R \setminus \{\sqrt{2}\}$ contains $\mathbb Q$ but is uncountable.

(d)  I'm not sure about this but I think it is false. **Could someone give an explicit example of an uncountable set $A$ containing $\mathbb Q$ that is open?**

(e) False. A counterexample is $\mathbb Q$ itself. We know that $\mathbb Q$ is neither [open nor closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116730) in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: @zhw. Notice the part in bold.

Comment: @zhw. I thought so too at first. Tricky to spot, but it's there.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't read the bold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that for (d) you actually want an uncountable set $A$ containing $\Bbb Q$ that is **not** open. An easy one is $[0,1]\cup\Bbb Q$. (In (a) you already gave an example of one that **is** open.)

Your other answers are correct.

Comment: Heh, I was a bit careless there. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @S.D.: You’re welcome! (I figured that it was basically just a typo or brief mental hiccup.)

Comment: Or $C\cup \mathbb Q,$ where $C$ is the Cantor set. This set has empty interior.