Are singletons in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ both closed and open?
For context: I am looking at $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology.
I know the singletons are closed. But are they open?
I thought about something along the lines of
{ $r$ } $= (r - \epsilon, r + \epsilon) \cap \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}}$
for  $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ being the subspace topology.
I thought that they are but someone said that is not true and I don't really understand why it wouldn't be.

I hope https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116721/are-the-rationals-a-closed-or-open-set-in-mathbbr may help you

For $\epsilon > 0$, does the open interval $(r - \epsilon, r + \epsilon)$ contain irrational numbers other than $r$?

How do you get $${r}=(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)\cap (\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)?$$

If $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, then every open subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ to which $r$ belongs contain some $r'\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. Therefore, $A\cap(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\ne\{r\}$. So, $\{r\}$ is not an open subset of $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

The existence of $r'$ here is merely assertion, of course, and requires proof.

Right, I overlooked that. Typical case of simply wanting something to be true rather than it actually being true. Thanks very much!

Hint: If $r$ is irrational, then $r\left(1+1/n\right)$ is irrational for all natural numbers $n.$
Given $\epsilon>0,$ pick $n$ such that $\frac1n<\frac\epsilon{|r|}.$

Then $r(1+1/n) < r + \epsilon$ so it follows that no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, we will still find an irrational number other than $r$ in the interval $(r - \epsilon, r + \epsilon)$. Thank you!

Well, when $r$ is negative, you have to be careful, but for all $r,$ $\left|r-r\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right|=\frac{|r|}n<\epsilon.$ @metamathics
